# Phonegap InAppBrowser - back button don't go to previous page

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm using Phonegap for my application and I need to display an external link in a InAppBrowser
but it looks like the back botton is not working as expecting: if I'm doing

```
var ref = window.open('www.example.com/a.html' , '_blank', 'location=no')
```

from from **a.html** page I clicked a link to **www.example.com/b.html** next time when I click back, the InAppBrowser is closed but it should go back to **a.html**.

Do you know how can I enable the 'navigation history' for InAppBrowser?

Thank you.

Comment: If you chick the Phone back button, It takes you to the previous intent not to the previous page on your web view. This means you have to add a back button in you page.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by tweaking the 'InAppBrowser.java'. I know this is little weird but this is the only choice I had. But, those little tweaks I made to the java file now allows me to navigate back within the pages in my app.

Here is the change to be made in InAppBrowser.java, In the 'run' method within showWebPage method, there will be a listener code something like this:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {     
                        closeDialog();
                    }
});
```

Below that line add the below code,

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {                   
@Override
     public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
             return true;               
         if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
             goBack();
             return true;
         }else {
             return false;
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Really helpful, worked like a charm on Cordova 3.0.0

Comment: I couldn't find `dialog.setOnDismissListener(...)` in **InAppBrowser.java** class.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the back button (assuming you're on android) and inject the history.back call into the InAppBrowser.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
    //do some checks to make sure the browser is open or 
    //whatever else you may need first, then:
    cordova.exec(null, null, "InAppBrowser", "injectScriptCode", ["history.back()"]);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Suresh Raja wrote, the referenced code doesn't exist anymore. you can add the suggested improved code (following) after this peace of code:

```
dialog.setInAppBroswer(getInAppBrowser());
```

suggested improved code:

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {                   
@Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
              return true;               
          if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
              if (inAppWebView.canGoBack()) {
                  inAppWebView.goBack();
              }
              else {
                  closeDialog();
              }
              return true;
          } else {
                return false;
          }
     }
});
```

this will close the application upon the last back press (which can solve another issue with the inAppBrowser.
Hope that helps

EDIT: you should add the `import android.content.DialogInterface` to get this work.